# Matlab Plot Issues

Tags: matlab

I have a very simple problem and I did not find a close answer over the staked history overflow.

I have computed `xcorr` for two vectors which is across minutely data on stock prices over couple of year.

I want to average the `xcorr` calculated for each hour (like average of `xcorr` for all observations for each hour say 00.00 to 00.59) for the given time period and then plot it against hour which are from 0 (or 00 hours) to 23 hours. I would like to get average `xcorr` for each hour and then plot this average `xcorr` over hours.

My plot should have average of `xcorr` across `y` axis and hours from 00 to 23 on x axis.

If useful, the following sample data can be used. I have already computed the `xcorr` and extracted the hours from the given time column.

```
05/04/2011 05:02    120.84  108.14

05/04/2011 05:04    120.83  108.14

05/04/2011 05:06    120.83  108.15

05/04/2011 05:07    120.8   108.11

05/04/2011 05:08    120.8   108.08

05/04/2011 05:09    120.78  108.08

05/04/2011 05:10    120.81  108.08

05/04/2011 05:12    120.81  108.08

05/04/2011 05:17    120.81  108.07

05/04/2011 05:19    120.72  108.04

05/04/2011 05:22    120.74  108.05

05/04/2011 05:23    120.7   108.03

05/04/2011 05:24    120.67  108.04
```

Many thanks in advance.

Anees

Comment: Any approach on solving this 'by hand' - any averaging, maybe using `for`-loops that you have tried?

Comment: You need to put the xcorr data for each hour in separate columns of a matrix, say, 'A'. So the columns of your matrix 'A' represent xcorr data for different hours. And let's say you'll have 'H+1' hours in total (starting from zero). Then you could say: plot(0:H,mean(A)) or if your hours start from '1', you could write: plot(mean(A))

Comment: I have actually the time series of prices over minutes and calculated the xcorr between the two series. Now I want the average of all xcorr present within the hourly limits against that hour for all hours. It would be nice if I can get a script that does it all along the lines.